# Firebird Membership Provider on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, firebird

I'm currently developing a website on ASP.NET and using Sql Membership Provider for authentication because I am using SQL Server for the database. However my boss decided to just connect to the existing Firebird database their local system is currently using and discard the SQL Server database. I've been looking online for sample codes for a long time now and I haven't seen a working one. Most of what I've seen are obsolete codes and the ones I tried were not working and gives errors. Can anyone give me a sample? Which includes what do I have to put in the web config and what dlls should I be including.

Comment: If it's not a legacy code, I would not use membership providers. These are obsolete in ASP.NET world now. ASP.NET Identity might be better solution.

Comment: I haven't heard of it. Is it also easy to implement?

Comment: Read http://www.asp.net/identity . It's not difficult.

Comment: But it is only available in vs2013.i am using 2010.

Comment: Then you're stuck with membership (https://sourceforge.net/p/firebird/NETProvider/ci/master/tree/WebProviders/).